# Calculating DataFrame columns based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas

Having `DataFrame` like so:

```py
# comments are the equations that have to be done to calculate the given column
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'item_tolerance': [230, 115, 155],
    'item_intake': [250,100,100], 
    'open_items_previous_day': 0,  # df.item_intake.shift() + df.open_items_previous_day.shift() - df.items_shipped.shift() + df.items_over_under_sla.shift()
    'total_items_to_process': 0,  # df.item_intake + df.open_items_previous_day
    'sla_relevant': 0,  # df.item_tolerance if df.open_items_previous_day + df.item_intake > df.item_tolerance else df.open_items_previous_day + df.item_intake
    'items_shipped': [230, 115, 50],
    'items_over_under_sla': 0  # df.items_shipped - df.sla_relevant
})
```

|  | item_tolerance | item_intake | open_items_previous_day | total_items_to_process | sla_relevant | items_shipped | items_over_under_sla |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 230 | 250 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 230 | 0 |
| 1 | 115 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 115 | 0 |
| 2 | 155 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 50 | 0 |

I'd like to calculate all the columns that have comments in them. I've tried using `df.apply(some_method, axis=1)` to perform row wise calculations but the problem is that I don't have the access to the previous row inside `some_method(row)`.

To give a little more explanation, what I'm trying to achieve is for example: `df.items_over_under_sla = df.items_shipped - df.sla_relevant` but `df.sla_relevant` is based on equation which needs `df.open_items_previous_day` which needs `df.open_items_previous_day` which needs the previous row to be calculated. This is the problem, I need to calculate rows based on the values from this row and the previous one.

What is the correct approach to such problem?

Comment: Please provide sample output. What does comments mean ?

Comment: Have you tried perform your calculations using column series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calculating each column with a different operation I suggest obtaining them individually:

```
df['open_items_previous_day'] = df['item_intake'].shift(fill_value=0) + df['open_items_previous_day'].shift(fill_value=0) - df['items_shipped'].shift(fill_value=0) + df['items_over_under_sla'].shift(fill_value=0)
df['total_items_to_process'] = df['item_intake'] + df['open_items_previous_day']
df = df.assign(sla_relevant=np.where(df['open_items_previous_day'] + df['item_intake'] > df['item_tolerance'], df['item_tolerance'], df['open_items_previous_day'] + df['item_intake']))
df['items_over_under_sla'] = df['items_shipped'] - df['sla_relevant']
df

Out[1]: 
         item_tolerance  item_intake  open_items_previous_day  total_items_to_process  sla_relevant  items_shipped  items_over_under_sla
0                   230          250                        0                     250           230            230                     0
1                   115          100                       20                     120           115            115                     0
2                   155          100                      -15                      85            85             50                   -35
```

The problem that you are facing is not about having to use the previous row (you are working around that just fine using the *shift* function). The real problem here is that all columns that you are trying to get (except for *total_items_to_process*) depend on each other, therefore you can't get the rest of the columns without having one of them first (or assuming it is zero initially).

That's why you are going to get different results depending on which column you've calculated first.